# Button to control hovertext

Tags: r, button, plotly

I'm making trace type plots with lots of traces, and the result is a lot of hovertexts. However, traces with Y values within a certain (normal) Y range are not very relevant to the viewer. Therefore I would like to add buttons to my plot which, when pressed, turns hovertexts partially on and off, so only the extreme Y values' hovertexts are shown.

I already made the code to remove the normal Y range's hovertexts in the definition of the hovertext:

```
  # Construct hovertext
  tmp$hovertext <- as.character(tmp$value)
  
  # SD values between -2 and 2 replaces hovertext with ""
  tmp$hovertext[abs(tmp$SD) < 2] <- ""
```

I wonder if this is useful at all as input for a button definition.

Note: I've looked for this with no result. I apologise if it's a duplicate.

Thanks in advance.

Jens

Answer (score 0):

I think you could combine `layout` `updatemenus` with a `button` and `restyle` ... maybe you can adapt the code below to your needs? Probably it's not the most efficient solution, but I am experimenting with plotly myself these days (no expert solution :D)

```
dat <- dplyr::tibble(X=rnorm(10),
                     Y=rnorm(10),
                     LAB1=X,
                     LAB2=c(rep("",8),"1","2"))

plotly::plot_ly() %>%
    plotly::add_trace(data=dat,
                      x=~X,
                      y=~Y,
                      text=paste("X:",dat$LAB1),
                      hoverinfo="text",
                      type="scatter",
                      mode="markers") %>%
    plotly::layout(
        updatemenus=list(
            list(
                type = "buttons",
                y = 0.8,
                buttons = list(
                    list(method = "restyle",
                         args = list("text",paste("X:",dat$LAB1)),
                         label = "LABEL_1"),
                    list(method = "restyle",
                         args = list("text",paste("X:",dat$LAB2)),
                         label = "LABEL_2")))))
```